# Order PHP Gallery by Filename

Tags: php, gallery

My PHP is a bit shaky, I've tried a natsort and scandir, but maybe I havn't been using them right, anyway, I need this PHP script to show the images in order - any help would be greatly appareciated. Thanks in advance!

```
/** settings **/
$images_dir = 'preload-images-hair/';
$thumbs_dir = 'preload-images-hair-thumbs/';
$thumbs_width = 200;
$images_per_row = 4;

/** generate photo gallery **/
$image_files = get_files($images_dir);
if(count($image_files)) {
$index = 0;
foreach($image_files as $index=>$file) {
    $index++;
    $thumbnail_image = $thumbs_dir.$file;
    if(!file_exists($thumbnail_image)) {
        $extension = get_file_extension($thumbnail_image);
        if($extension) {
            make_thumb($images_dir.$file,$thumbnail_image,$thumbs_width);
        }
    }
    echo '<a href="',$images_dir.$file,'" data-lightbox-gallery="gallery" class="lightbox" rel="gallery"><img src="',$thumbnail_image,'" /></a>';
    if($index % $images_per_row == 0) { echo '<div class="clear"></div>'; }
}
echo '<div class="clear"></div>';
}
else {
echo '<p>There are no images in this gallery.</p>';
 }
```

Comment: what order do you want them in?  When you read from a directory, files are usually ordered by created time.

Comment: Sorted by file name please

Answer (score 0):

Your `$index++` seems wrong and you can probably remove that.  After you run `get_files` (i'm assuming it returns an array of file names) run [sort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) on that result.

```
$image_files = get_files($images_dir);
sort($image_files);
```